# conversion of BCD to unsigned char

Tags: c

I have a unsigned char array containing the following value : "\x00\x91\x12\x34\x56\x78\x90";
That is number being sent in Hexadecimal format.
Additionally, it is in BCD format : 00 in byte, 91 in another byte (8 bits)

On the other side I require to decode this value as 0091234567890.

I'm using the following code:

```
unsigned int conver_bcd(char *p,size_t length)
  {
         unsigned int convert =0;
         while (length--)
          {
             convert = convert * 100 + (*p >> 4) * 10 + (*p & 15);
             ++p
           }
       return convert;
```

}

However, the result which I get is 1430637214.

What I understood was that I'm sending hexadecimal values (\x00\x91\x12\x34\x56\x78\x90) and my bcd conversion is acting upon the decimal values.

Can you please help me so that I can receive the output as 00911234567890 in Char

Regards
Karan

Comment: You have an overflow problem. An `unsigned int` is (most likely) 32 bits, i.e. four bytes. There is no way you can fit 91 billion in a 32-bit variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are simply overflowing your unsigned int, which is presumably 32 bits on your system. Change:

```
     unsigned int convert =0;
```

to:

```
     uint64_t convert = 0;
```

in order to guarantee a 64 bit quantity for `convert`.

Make sure you add:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast char to unsigned char, then print it with %02x.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char array[] = "\x00\x91\x12\x34\x56\x78\x90";
    int size = sizeof(array) - 1;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%02x", (unsigned char )array[i]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change return type to `unsigned long long` to insure you have a large enough integer.

Change `p` type to an unsigned type.

Print value with leading zeros.

```
unsigned long long conver_bcd(const char *p, size_t length) {
  const unsigned char *up = (const unsigned char*) p;
  unsigned long long convert =0;
  while (length--) {
    convert = convert * 100 + (*up >> 4) * 10 + (*up & 15);
    ++up;
    }
  return convert;
}

const char *p =  "\x00\x91\x12\x34\x56\x78\x90";
size_t length = 7;
printf( "%0*llu\n", (int) (length*2), conver_bcd(p, length));
// 00911234567890
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. Yes, it was a problem of unsigned int overflow - dint realise that. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2955288 When I tried your accepted answer (change your post from `unsigned int` to `uint64_t`), I received `18446743384944119346`.  Hmmm?